# Why does NPM Cache clean randomly fail with EPERM on TFS Build Server?

Tags: node.js, tfs, npm, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am using TFS source control and 2015 TFS Build Server.

I setup script to build on a build server. The first step is to clear the cache, because if not, it would randomly fail due to random error.

But now, almost half of the time it gives this new error:

```
2016-07-08T19:39:32.2041280Z > npm cache clean

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodeJs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clean"

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! node v4.4.7

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! path C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! code EPERM

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! errno -4048

2016-07-08T19:39:40.5819362Z npm ERR! syscall rmdir

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache'

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!     at Error (native)

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache']

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Windows\\ServiceProfiles\\NetworkService\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache' }

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR! 

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6288231Z npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6757133Z npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

2016-07-08T19:39:40.6757133Z npm ERR!     C:\Work\9\s\Atlas.Prototype\src\starterproject\npm-debug.log

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodeJs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "cleancache"

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! node v4.4.7

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! angular2@5.0.4-v1.0.0 cleancache: `npm cache clean`

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! Exit status 4294963248

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! 

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! Failed at the angular2@5.0.4-v1.0.0 cleancache script 'npm cache clean'.

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2 package,

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7382460Z npm ERR! not with npm itself.

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7538723Z npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

2016-07-08T19:39:40.7538723Z npm ERR!     npm cache clean
```

How is it possible that it gives "permission" error when run, but when run again it succeeds, and if running again a 3rd time it is random?

What would be the steps to ensure `npm cache clean` is successful 100% of the time?

Comment: Builds running in parallel maybe?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?  I'm seeing it with node 6.9.5 and npm  v3.10.10.

Comment: No I did not. The only solution I found was to avoid building anything Node related on a windows server. Now, on `git commit`, I have a hook which simply creates a local .Zip of my entire project (using a node_module called `zip-dir`, you can also use `gulp-zip`). So the zip is prebuilt and ready to deploy, then commit that to the deployment TFS server. TFS then simply extracts and copies those files to the web server directly. Not the best but it works for a very small team.

Answer (score 0):

As the issue the random, it may not caused by permission.

Try to upgrade the npm to the latest version, to see whether the issue persists. Also, as @Christian.K mentioned, you may check if there is parallel build.